# Good source for English grammar exercises

Tags: grammar, synonyms, antonyms, conjugations

A friend of mine recently experienced a stroke due to complications from COVID. He is dealing with expressive and receptive aphasia, and struggles to conjugate some verb tenses, remember synonyms, and some other things. He is able to learn and memorize the 'right answers' to these questions, but it seems like he has to create new mental pathways to do it. I was thinking that a good book full of grammar exercises might help. For example, I'm looking for something with lots of repetitive exercises like this, covering many different basic patterns:

```
Repeat the following pattern:

Yesterday I watered the lawn. The lawn was watered by me. (water)

Yesterday she __________ a new car. The car __________ by her. (buy)
Yesterday they __________ a movie. The movie __________ by them. (watch)
Yesterday he __________ the guitar. The guitar __________ by him. (play)
Yesterday we __________ a book. The book __________ by us. (read)
Yesterday I __________ a letter. The letter __________ by me. (write)
```

etc. etc.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Please see the last bullet point on [this help page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (Note that if the linked resource list doesn't help you, then requests for resources are allowed--within reason--on [Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.englishgrammar.org/exercises/) online platform.